# Which 3D applications currently uses Vulkan API?

Tags: vulkan

I'm a newbie in terms of CG world. I'm curious to know about the applications that use Vulkan API and their performances compared to other APIs.

As I read, Vulkan has more access to the graphic cards which helps in performance. If so, do the current rendering engines use it?

Solidworks, Revit, Sketchup, Unity3D, Unreal Engine, After Effects, etc. ?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm a newbie in terms of CG world. I'm curious to know about the applications that use Vulkan API and their performances compared to other APIs

There are some popular magazine websites, such as [PCGamer](https://www.pcgamer.com/doom-benchmarks-return-vulkan-vs-opengl/2/) and [AnandTech](https://www.anandtech.com/show/11223/quick-look-vulkan-3dmark-api-overhead) that has some comparison charts between other rendering APIs.

**PCGamer compares OpenGL vs Vulkan for Doom (2016)**
[image]

**AnandTech compares Vulkan vs DirectX12 API Overhead**
[image]

I would argue that comparisons make sense on the application-level - one API wouldn't necessarily be better on all occasions than the others. It totally depends on how the graphics developers of the software have architected their system to unlock the APIs full potential.

---

> As I read, Vulkan has more access to the graphic cards which helps in performance. If so, do the current rendering engines use it?
>   < 
>   Solidworks, Revit, Sketchup, Unity3D, Unreal Engine, After Effects, etc. ?

[Wikipedia: Software that supports Vulkan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan_(API)#Software_that_supports_Vulkan) page has a list of software that supports Vulkan API. As for your question, quoting from Wiki page:

> - Unreal Engine 4 – In February 2016, Epic Games announced Unreal Engine 4 support for Vulkan at Samsung's Galaxy S7 Unpacked
>     event.[64][65]
> - Unity – The engine has support for Vulkan since version 5.6.

There's plenty of others which are also popular, video games and game engines listed in the Wikipedia page, such as:

- Dota 2
- Doom
- vkQuake
- Star Citizen
- Wolfenstein II
- CryEngine
- Source 2